# Mounting Points and File Permissions

Tags: mount

I have a system with dual boot - Ubuntu 12.04 ans openSUSE 12.3

I logged into Ubuntu and i am able to mount openSUSE partition without any issues by entering fstab UUID command with default options.

The question has to do with File Permissions.
Will the File Permissions get carried over to Ubuntu system?

Because i find the first level of directories are mounted as root/root.

If i go into /home/harish folder in opensuse partition, it actually owned by ubuntu user with same uid.

It is not mounting entire partition as root/root. instead it is mapping uids and gids of opensuse user and ubuntu user and set the permissions accordingly.

Is this behavior correct? I want to mount a ext4 partition into ubuntu as root/root, but need to have file permissions as `rwx-rwx-rwx` for all the files and folders. is this doable?

Thanks,
Harish Pathangay